# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid CanActivate guard

Tags: angular7

Im newbee for angular 7 and now trying to implement CanActive, but im getting error :

[image]

Can anyone guide me to overcome this. My code samples are as follows :

**auth.guard.ts :**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth-service.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
              private myRoute: Router){
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.auth.isLoggednIn()){
      return true;
    } else {
      this.myRoute.navigate(["login"]);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just for the record, I had the same error stated a little different in Angular 6: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: guard is undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a promise as an `if` condition and the promise may throw an error.
So you could either simply wrap it with a try/catch block or you could wrap it within another promise instance and return the auth result by using `resolve` to pass it further down the line:

```js
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
       return new Promise(resolve =>
         this.auth.isLoggednIn()
           .then(status: boolean => {
             if(status === false) {
               this.myRoute.navigate(["login"]);
             }
             resolve(status);
           })
           .catch(() => {
             this.myRoute.navigate(["login"]);
             resolve(false);
             // ... or any other way you want to handle such error case
           })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
   return this.auth.isLoggednIn() ? true : this.myRoute.navigate(["login"]);
```

I got **the SAME error message** when I did the following:

```
   canDeactivate(component: CreateEmployeeComponent): boolean {
        if(component.createEmployeeForm.dirty) {
           return confirm('Are you sure you want to discard your changes?');
        }
        return true;
   }
```

So I solved the problem in the following way:

```
    canDeactivate(component: CreateEmployeeComponent): boolean {
         return component.createEmployeeForm.dirty 
                ? confirm('Are you sure you want to discard your changes?') 
                : true;    
    }
```

I'm not sure it works for you, but you can at least give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this same error.

The reason I got this was I had declared (in my routing module `app-routing.module.ts`) my guard to be `canLoad` but later on I changed the method (in guard file) to CanActivate, so naturally Angular got confused.

Answer (score -2):

Check that the class given into routes (in this case `MyGuardClass`) `{path: 'aPath', component: myComponent, canActivate: [MyGuardClass]}` implements `CanActivate` [as documented here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#description)

Comment: @banan3'14 I thought there is no Need to explicit it... as when you specify a Class that `canActivate`, it can be whichever class that implements CanActivate... in the above pointed documentation the MyGuardClass is CanActivateTeam

Comment: I am sure that most people who read your answer have already read the documentation thoroughly and sending them back to it is little help for them. You make it even more vague changing the names without reason.